# Odd IE8 html5shiv behavior

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-8

Consider the following...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        main{
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            margin:0 auto;
            border:5px solid red;
            display:none;  
        }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </main>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //load some external content then on callback...
        $('main').show();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Works fine in every browser but IE8 (shocker). If you remove the `display:none;` then all is well, so I am assuming this is the problem. But why?

**What I am trying to accomplish**

`<main>` is my wrapper which contains a `<nav>`, `<footer>` and a `<div>` to inject content into via an ajax call. There is a slight awkward flicker when the site first loads and injects the landing page content into the empty `<div>` content holder. Not a huge deal, but I wanted something easier on the eyes so I added a `display:none;` to the `main` style definition and added a `show()` or `fadeIn()` once the content was loaded to prevent the flicker. Works... except in IE8. Its as if `<main>` loses its `display` defined by the shiv and defaults to `inline`.

**Things I have tried**

I have replaced the `<main>` tag with `<div id="main">` and this works fine. But I am trying to embrace HTML5 and would like to use the `<main>` tag.

I know this is minor, I just get frustrated when I don't understand the *why*.

Comment: add `document.createElement("main")` to your code

Comment: Shiv seems to not work at times when it's not local. Set that stuff up locally and put it after the jquery library. Here is something extra to deal with IE8 when it comes to css3 selectors http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @KevinB Isn't that what the `html5shiv.js` does for you? Its included in the head before any js or css is added.

Comment: Added a local version of the shiv and added that selectivizer library to the head and no dice :(

Comment: I don't see anywhere within the shiv where it is doing that, though of course i'm looking at a minified version which is hard to read.

Comment: @KevinB Look [here](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js) around line 109. This is the js library I am importing in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't take complete credit for this... the other developer I work with is a jQuery yoda....

jQuery appears to, by default, add a css style of 'display:inline;' to tag elements. Because 'main' is not defined as known element (such as a div) in IE, it defaults to 'inline'. A few solutions may be:

```
$('main').css('display','block');
```

or for fade:

```
var $main = $('main');
$main.css('display','block').hide().show(600); //--not yet tested
```

Comment: Very nice! That worked, thanks. That jQuery yoda must get laid on daily basis... what a stud! lol

Comment: err... I don't know... I will ask... may make things uncomfortable, usually I only bring up when he is cranky (e.g 'dude, you soo need to get laid') or when I am cranky (e.g. 'go ...uhm... lay yourself')